# django cannot find management command

Tags: django

I am using django 1.5.1 and trying to get moving the management command. I have an app called patient and here is the directory structure.

```
patient/
├── __init__.py
├── forms.py
├── management
│   ├── __init.py__
│   └── commands
│       ├── __init.py__
│       └── recall1.py
├── models.py
├── urls.py
├── views.py
```

Here is what happens when I try to run the recall1 command:

```
$ python manage.py recall1
Unknown command: 'recall1'
```

Here is how my code looks like:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from recall.model import PatientRecalls, RecallType, RecallMessage
from patient.model import Patient

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = '<patient_id patient_id ...>'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for patient_id in args:
            try:
                patient = Patient.objects.get(pk=int(patient_id))
            except Patient.DoesNotExist:
                raise CommandError('Patient "%s" does not exist' % patient_id)

            patient.opened = False
            patient.save()

            self.stdout.write('Successfully closed patient "%s"' % patient_id)
```

What wrong do I need to correct before I can run this thing? The app is running great, except for this issue..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your filename `__init.py__` should actually be `__init__.py` both in the directories `management/` and `commands/`

Comment: Duh. Can't believe I missed this. Thanks.

Comment: Nuts ... I have the same problem, but didn't happen to make that particular mistake :)